# Joda ISOChronology getInstance() changing during processing

Tags: java, jodatime

Joda 2.2 LocalDateTime is returning a datetime based on a different TimeZone during processing. I believe there were some changes in 2.3 to address some race conditions around the ISOChronology DateTimeZone cache, but in this case I don't believe it is the cause of the issue.

Up to a certain point in execution The LocalDateTime is based on the default jvm timezone of Europe/London as I'd expect. But after a while, it switched to be based on UTC. This gives results as follows:

20150409-09:10:45.281 DEBUG [Thread-1] LocalDateTime=2015-04-09T09:10:45.281 **ISOChronology.getInstance(): ISOChronology[Europe/London]** DateTimeZone.getDefault(): Europe/London index: 20 UTC index: 12

Then later (and consistently from that point on)

20150409-09:10:46.125 DEBUG [Thread-0] LocalDateTime=2015-04-09T08:10:46.125 **ISOChronology.getInstance(): ISOChronology[UTC]** DateTimeZone.getDefault(): Europe/London index: 20 UTC index: 12

LocalDateTime calls ISOChronology.getInstance() to identify the local DateTimeZone. ISOChronology then calls DateTimeZone.getDefault() to return the default local timezone. What I can't understand is that DateTimeZone.getDefault() is not changing, yet ISOChronology.getInstance() is switching from Europe/London to UTC. I am also printing out the internal indices that ISOChronology would use to look them up in its fast cache. They seem to be unchanged. Does anyone have any explanation why this could be happening?

Edited:

This is the logging code:

```
logger.debug("LocalDateTime=" + new LocalDateTime() + " ISOChronology.getInstance(): " + ISOChronology.getInstance() 
    + " DateTimeZone.getDefault(): " + DateTimeZone.getDefault()
    + " index: " + (System.identityHashCode(DateTimeZone.getDefault()) & (64 - 1))
    + " UTC index: " + (System.identityHashCode(DateTimeZone.UTC) & (64 - 1)));
```

It is creating an empty constructor LocalDateTime, and checking what values ISOChronology.getInstance() and DateTimeZone.getDefault() are returning at that point in time, as well as the indexes ISOChronology would use internally to look them up.

Comment: Are you sure you're not constructing a `LocalDateTime` value using a time zone? Can you reproduce this in a short but complete program? We don't know anything about your code at the moment - including exactly what your logging is...

Comment: I can't reproduce it outside of the context of the application that's displaying the issue unfortunately. Which is why I am wondering what factors could cause specifically ISOChronology.getInstance() to return a different value in the same jvm  session. This is the logging code:

Comment: Please edit the logging code into the question itself, instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: Logging code added to original question

Comment: Your logging code's quotation marks do not match up - is this the original code?

Comment: It is except for the purpose of pasting it here I edited out an identifying string at the start. The calls are unchanged. I've corrected the quotation mark that was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be that Protostuff (a library that provides features to auto serialize objects over Protobuff) is in this case overwriting ISOChronology as it constructs a DateTime it is deserializing as part of a payload received from our server. The stack that precedes the ISOChronology changing is:

```
ISOChronology.getInstance() line: 79    
DateTime(BaseDateTime).<init>() line: 61    
DateTime.<init>() line: 171 
NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Constructor, Object[]) line: not available [native method]   
NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: not available 
DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: not available 
Constructor<T>.newInstance(Object...) line: not available   
RuntimeEnv$DefaultInstantiator<T>.newInstance() line: 300   
RuntimeSchema<T>.newMessage() line: 345 
ByteArrayInput.mergeObject(T, Schema<T>) line: 374  
RuntimeUnsafeFieldFactory$13$1.mergeFrom(Input, T) line: 773    
RuntimeSchema<T>(MappedSchema<T>).mergeFrom(Input, T) line: 188 
IOUtil.mergeFrom(byte[], int, int, T, Schema<T>, boolean) line: 43  
ProtobufIOUtil.mergeFrom(byte[], T, Schema<T>) line: 95
```

The values of cCache in ISOChronology before and after these reflection calls are -

before:

```
cCache: {Europe/London=ISOChronology[Europe/London], UTC=ISOChronology[UTC]}
```

after:

```
cCache: {Europe/London=ISOChronology[UTC], UTC=ISOChronology[UTC]}
```

Edit: For anyone facing a similar problem with DateTime etc. becoming unstable this is a protostuff thread about it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protostuff/GmFldwwexUk